# Crud Web API C# using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I have an issue in the API, because I have a foreign key in a class in the post/put method it asks me for the information of the both classes. For the get method it makes sense because I want to print the information in the frontend, btw I'm using blazor for the frontend. I'm also using SQLite for the database.

Here are the classes - `Certification`:

```
public partial class Certification
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Exam> Exams { get; set; } = new List<Exam>();
}

public partial class Exam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public long? CertificationId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public long MinimumGrade { get; set; }

    public virtual Certification? Certification { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ExamAttempt> ExamAttempts { get; set; } = new List<ExamAttempt>();
}
```

I'm using Swagger to see what happens in the backend.

[It asks for all this information when I'm trying to add an exam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOGH7.png)

[When I only want to asks for this information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giday.png)

Take in consideration that in the frontend I want to make a crud of exams for each certification.

Comment: use separate class for Input then Create or update object in your business logic it will work. `using Database entities is not a best approach`

Answer (score 2):

You should not mix your database models with your request models, this is bad practice and a security risk.

You should create DTOs and have the data minimal as per operation, so if you want to add a certification to an exam, you should do this seperately to adding an exam.

Here are DTO examples:

```cs
public class CertificationDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
}

public class ExamDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long? CertificationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public long MinimumGrade { get; set; }
}

public class ExamCertDto
{
    public int ExamId { get; set; }
    public long CertificationId { get; set; }
}
```

And you can map your DTO to a database model like so

```cs
public IActionResult AddExam(ExamDto examDto)
{
    Exam e = new {
        Name = examDto.Name,
        MinimumGrade = examDto.MinumumGrade
    };

    dbcontext.Exams.Add(e);

    return Ok(e.Id);
}
```

Or if you want to add a Cert to an exam:

```cs
public IActionResult AddCertToExam(ExamCertDto ec)
{
    var exam = dbcontext.Exams.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == ec.ExamId);
    exam.CertificationId = ex.CertificationId;

    dbcontex.Save();

    return Ok(exam.Id);
}
```

If you really have to have the two in one operation you just change Exam to something like this:

```cs
public class ExamDto 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public long? CertificationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public long MinimumGrade { get; set; }
    public ExamCertDto Certificate { get; set; };
}
```

The issues is the request objects have to match exactly, this is the reason why you have to map them. Otherwise don't use an object and maybe use the `HttpContext.Current.Request` properties.

FYI you will need to make extra checks in the examples I provided or it will not be robust e.g. checking that the exam and certification id's actually exist before adding.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Request` does not exist in ASP.NET Core, btw. Use `IHttpContextAccessor` instead.

Comment: @Dai That's the one I meant to put.